# How to make my app accessible from any other app like Google Translate app?

Tags: java, android, google-translate

I saw in the video on Google youtube channel([there it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xtEp55MKRE)) that Google Translate can open its own window in any app if you copy words.

I need it to my translation/dictionary app to add copied words there. 
Must i have a supreme authority to do that? And how to do that? Or what else can perform this functionality?

Comment: Draw on top. Any app can do that.

Comment: With permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer for this question at [Drawing over other applications in Android [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260709/4037220).

Basically what you need is to draw over other applications. As stated in the Stackoverflow link I have posted above. You will have to use [WindowManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html), which draws a view on the root on Android Window Manager.

For more information you can visit the [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22260709/4037220)